# Upgraded Xcode 4.3.2 Showing Error

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator

I just upgraded to Xcode 4.3.2 (the newest version). When I try to run an app that I built in previous versions of Xcode, this error pops up:

> Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
>
> No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version.
>       Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application
>       or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

I made sure to change the iOS deployment target to 5.1.  How can I get rid of this error?

All I did was press build and run.  I want to run on the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Are you sure you selected the emulator instead of an iOS device in the upper-left Scheme menu?

Comment: No, how do I do so? I'm not new to Xcode but I just can't figure this out for some reason.

Comment: It's the menu right next to the stop button, in the upper-left side of the window. Click on it and select the iPhone or iPad simulator instead of the iOS device.

Comment: Ah, thank you that was simple.  If you'd like to answer this question below I'd love to give credit where it is deserved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set Xcode to build to the simulator as illustrated below.

[image]